# Best practice for adding and editing MySQL data with HTML/PHP/jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, crud

I have some **HTML** forms (generated by PHP) for adding and editing **MySQL** data. I use the same forms for adding and editing. I'm beginning on a new project and was wondering if my previous technique is the right approach for adding and editing data. I'd like to make it right from the beginning :) Maybe these days jQuery and AJAX can be of help for this? Anyone know any good *CRUD (create, read, update, & delete)* plugins/scripts?

Basically I call a function with the form, passing a variable with the current data, if any.

I have two examples.

**Example 1 - year form:**

```
echo "From: \n";
echo "<select name=\"startYear\">\n";
     formYears($startYearWeek[0]);
echo "</select>\n";

function formYears($default = null) {
    $year = 2008;
    while(date("Y")+1 >= $year) {
        if(($default != NULL) && ($year == $default)) {
            echo "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"" . $year . "\">" . $year . "</option>\n";
        } else if(($default == NULL) && ($year == date("Y"))) {
            echo "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"" . $year . "\">" . $year . "</option>\n";  
        } else {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $year . "\">" . $year . "</option>\n";
        }
        $year++;
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - user form:**

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="userAdd">
    <?php fullUserForm($postArr); ?>
    <input name="userAddSubmit" type="submit" value="Lägg till användare" />
</form>


<?php function fullUserForm($defaultUser = null) { ?>
    <?php
    if($_SESSION['admin'] != "true") {
        echo "*Användarnamn:<br /><input name=\"username\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$defaultUser['username']."\">";
        echo "<span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\">".$defaultUser['username']."</span><br><br>\n";
    } else {
        echo "*Användarnamn:<br /><input name=\"username\" type=\"text\" value=\"".$defaultUser['username']."\"><br><br>";
    }
    ?>
    *Förnamn:<br /><input name="fName" type="text" value="<?php echo $defaultUser['fName']; ?>" /><br><br>
    *Efternamn:<br /><input name="lName" type="text" value="<?php echo $defaultUser['lName']; ?>"  /><br><br>
    Mobiltelefon:<br /><input name="mobilePhone" type="text" value="<?php echo $defaultUser['mobilePhone']; ?>" /><br><br>
    Alternativ telefon:<br /><input name="altPhone" type="text" value="<?php echo $defaultUser['altPhone']; ?>" /><br><br>
    *E-post:<br /><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $defaultUser['email']; ?>" /><br><br>
    <?php
    if($_SESSION['admin'] != "true") {
        echo "*Roll:<br /><input name=\"role\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$defaultUser['role']."\">";
        echo "<span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\">".$defaultUser['role']."</span><br><br>\n";
    } else {
        echo "*Roll:<br /><input name=\"role\" type=\"text\" value=\"".$defaultUser['role']."\"><br><br>";
    }
    ?>
    Födelsedag (ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD):<br /><input name="birthday" type="text" value="<?php echo $defaultUser['birthday']; ?>" /><br><br>
    *Önskat lösenord:<br /><input name="pswd1" type="password" value="<?php echo $defaultUser['pswd']; ?>" /><br><br>
    *Dubbelkoll av lösenordet:<br /><input name="pswd2" type="password" value="<?php echo $defaultUser['pswd']; ?>" /><br><br>
    <br />
    *obligatoriska fält<br />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: jqGrid, datatables, DrasticGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times there is no single right way. Often times there are multiple approaches with some being recommended over others. You just have to see what works for you and the size of your application. As you progress, your opinions on the various approaches will probably change.

If you are looking for something to handle a lot of this for you, then you might want to check out a PHP framework. I know that Laravel offers a lot of form building utilities.

Now if you want my personal recommendation, if you aren't using a framework, then I try and leave most of my HTML out of echo statements. This makes the HTML much easier to maintain. Instead, I would do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echoIfValueExists('age') ?>" />
```